# F# type error in function return value

Tags: c#, ios, .net, f#, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to implement the following code snippet in F#:

```
    // Method style
void Callback (NSNotification notification)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Received a notification UIKeyboard", notification);
}

void Setup ()
{
    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver (UIKeyboard.WillShowNotification, Callback);
}
```

I have done the following:

```
let toggleKeyboard(notification : NSNotification) = 
    Console.WriteLine ("Received a notification UIKeyboard", notification)

NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIKeyboard.WillShowNotification, toggleKeyboard) |> ignore
```

This seems like a straightforward implementation, however I get a type error:

`This expression was expected to have type    'Action<NSNotification>'    but here has type    ''a -> unit' (FS0001) (Dissertation)`

I'm not really sure how to make my method return a `Action<NSNotification>` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes F# will automatically cast functions to `Action<T>` or `Func<T>` types, but you can also explicitly wrap your function in an `Action<T>` like this:

```
let foo x = printfn "%s" x
let action = System.Action<string>(foo)
action.Invoke("hey") // prints hey
```

Or in your case:

```
...AddObserver(UIKeyboard.WillShowNotification, System.Action<NSNotification>(toggleKeyboard)) |> ignore
```